A question about general equations of Hyperbolas
We know that the general equation for a hyperbola is $$\sqrt{(x-\alpha)^2+(y-\beta)^2}=e\cdot\frac{|lx+my+n|}{\sqrt{l^2+m^2}}$$ where $(\alpha, \beta)$ is the focus of the hyperbola, $e>1$ is the eccentricity and $lx+my+n=0$ is the directrix. For future answer purposes, I will write the expanded form of this equation below, as it may prove to be helpful: $$x^2(m^2-l^2(e^2-1))+y^2(l^2-m^2(e^2-1))-2lme^2xy-x(2\alpha(l^2+m^2)+2lne^2)-y(2\beta(l^2+m^2)+2mne^2)+(l^2+m^2)(\alpha^2+\beta^2)-n^2e^2=0$$
However, there is also an alternate, much simpler representation of hyperbolas, namely $$L_1L_2=\pm s^2$$where $L_1$ and $L_2$ are any two intersecting lines where they are represented as $L_{1,2}: ax+by+c=0$ or equivalently $L_{1,2}: y-m_{1,2}x-c_{1,2}=0$, and $s$ is any positive real number.  Specifically, $L_1$ and $L_2$ represent the asymptotes of the given hyperbola, and choosing  either the $+$ or $-$ signs give us conjugate hyerbolas for the same set of asymptotes. Amazingly, this also gives us the property that adding the equations of two conjugate hyperbolas (with the same coefficients for $x^2$ and $y^2$) give us the combined equation of the asymptotes that describe them.
I have a few questions about this representation:
1. Why does this representation represent a hyperbola?
I have prepared a GeoGebra document to illustrate this: https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/tc6ghx8f
I think I have almost answered this question.
We consider the distances of the given point $(x, y)$ from each of the lines $L_1$ and $L_2$. Say we call these distances $d_1$ and $d_2$.  Then what that form basically says is that the product $d_1d_2=s^2$ (this $s$ is different than the original s) i.e. this product of distances is a constant. I suppose this can be treated as a defining property of hyperbolas, which would confirm the validity of this form. It also explains why choosing opposite signs gives us conjugate hyperbolas, since the "opposite quadrants" defined by the two asymptotes have the same sign of the function $L_1L_2(x,y)=(y-m_1x-c_1)(y-m_2x-c_2)$ so the adjacent quadrants have opposite signs.
2. Does every combination of two non-parallel lines $L_1$ and $L_2$ and the parameter $s$ give us a unique hyperbola?
Discounting for mere scalings of the coefficients of the two lines and $s$, intuitively I believe this must be true. Every pair of intersecting lines, however they are oriented, can have hyperbolas sandwiched in between them, and the parameter $s$ can be thought of as a "distance" parameter, where the smaller $s$ is, the closer the vertices of the hyperbola get to the intersection point of the two lines. And indeed, if we let $s\to 0$ we see that the limiting case of a hyperbola is just its asymptotes.
3. Does this form represent every possible hyperbola?
Again, intuitively this seems to be true. Every hyperbola must have a set of asymptotes, and it must also have some associated value of $s$ and an associated sign out of the $\pm$. However, I don't see how I can justify this.
4. How does this form convert to the focus-directrix form? In other words, how can we find the focus, directrix and eccentricity for any general hyperbola $L_1L_2=\pm s^2$?
I think this can be solved with the help of linear transformations. shifting the origin as well as scaling and rotating appropriately. However, I wasn't able to make any progress on this at all.
Any answers to any of my questions is appreciated! I'm just looking for some clarity on this topic, mainly about how do we rigidly prove all of the facts I presented.

Nice effort , +1 , though you should limit to 1 question per post. You may want to let (1) remain here. When that gets answered & you still have confusion on the other Issues , then you can make a new Post about (2) or (3) & then later when confusion persists , you can ask (4) !

@Prem thanks! I thought about separating all the questions, but I thought all 4 of them were related enough, and I’m answering most of them myself just looking for insights so I thought it wasn’t necessary

Point 1 is trivial if you choose as coordinate axes the bisectors of the angles formed by $L_1$ and $L_2$.

@Intelligentipauca yeah, that's kinda what I thought as well, some sort of shifting of the axes. Does changing the angle between the axes not mess up some of the things we take for granted in the coordinate plane though?

The bisectors of the angles formed by $_1$ and $_2$ are perpendicular, hence there is no change of angle.

@Intelligentipauca ah yes, i missed that detail. Can you explain the other three points as well?

The cosine of the angle between $L_1$ and $L_2$ gives you ${a^2-b^2\over a^2+b^2}$. You just need to find a point on the hyperbola, to finish off.

Given the foci $F_1,F_2$and a point $P$ on the hyperbola, the center is the midpoint $M:(h,k)$ of $F_1,F_2$. Letting the axes be centered at the center of the hyperbola and along and perpendicular to the foci line, the equation is $(\frac{x}{a})^2-(\frac{y}{b})^2=\pm 1,$ $-1$ for the conjugate if you choose the $a\geq b>0$. The asymptote form is $(\frac{x}{a})^2-(\frac{y}{b})^2=0.$ Given this coordinate system, the line pair through the origin can be written as $\frac{x}{a}=\pm \frac{y}{b}$ or $ay\pm bx=0,$ but remember in relation to the original coordinate system these are $a(y'-k)\pm b(x'-h)=0$ where the coordinates are given by the inverse rotation of the one taking $x',y'$ to $x,y$, given by the rotation angle $\theta:$ $x=x'\cos\theta+y'\sin\theta, y=-x'\sin\theta+y'\cos\theta,$ chosen such that the determinant of the matrix is $+1.$ The original lines therefore are general. So your questions reduce to finding the standard form from one of the two focus/directrix version of the equation. The standard way of doing this, given that this form is also of the $Ax'^2+Bx'y'+Cy'^2+Dx'+Ey'+F=0$ is to find the center by solving the linear system of partial derivatives wrt $x',y'$ set to zero, bringing the equation to the form $A(x-h)^2+B(x-h)(y-k)+C(y-k)^2+F'=0.$ The angle of rotation (given by $\tan{2\theta}=\frac{B}{A-C},$) the eigenvalues of the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}A&B/2\\B/2&C\end{pmatrix}$ appear as the equation becomes $-F'(\lambda_1 x^2+\lambda_2 y^2-1)=0.$ Given that we started with a hyperbola $e>1,$ the eigenvalues differ in sign and can be chosen to conform to the above.
